# SharePoint Designer - problem with task list

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, sharepoint-on-prem, tasks, workflow-tasks-list

we are using Workflow 2010 in SharePoint Designer 2013. We have workflow with Custom Task Process. However, we are struggling with several problems now.

In "Change the behavior of a single task" we have set two emails. First email is sent  to AssignedTo when task is pending. The second email is sent to AssignedTo when the task expires. Problem is that when Task is expires, task is cancelled. Emails content just information about current item. Then I noticed that I cannot  choosing field CurrentTask:AssignedTo anymore. Original action Email field has variable ID.ReturnValue.

[image]

If i want to add new action Email, lookup box for Current Task is empty.

[image]

I cannot even use action Set task field.

[image]

If I add action Start Approval action, task fields not missing. If I create new site in the same site collection, task fields in Custom Task Process are visible too.

Are these errors related to the fact that my task is cancelled when expires? Earlier tasks worked.

I tried to remove cache, but task fields still missing.

Thank you for help.